# PPTP password expired: how to fix on a linux client

Tags: linux, vpn, pptp

Today, I discovered my team's PPTP passwords expire and I had to figure this out by looking through log files (/var/log/messages).

Part 1 of my question is there a way I can start up my PPTP client service from Linux so that I get a precise error message on my screen indicating the password expired.  Currently when I launch from a KDE or GNOME applet all I see is a generic failure message.

Second, is there a tool on linux (preferably gui) that will allow me to change the password.   Linux is the client side;  I do not have login access on the server. This will eliminate my need to boot a VM or separate box to deal with expired passwords.

Thanks,

SetJmp

Answer (score 0):

I haven't find a GUI tool for that, but you can use the cmdline:

1. [check when your account is about to expire](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34610020/how-to-get-user-password-expiration-date-from-active-directory): `net user info --ipaddress=123.456.789.123  --user='DOMAIN\username'  'DOMAIN\username'`
2. [change the password](https://serverfault.com/questions/215983/change-windows-ad-password-from-linux): `smbpasswd -r 123.456.789.123 -U 'DOMAIN\username'`

Answer (score -1):

Yes, there is a tool to change a password. Sorry, it's a command line tool. As root type the following:

```
passwd <username>
```

Then try to start your connection as you do usually provided you changed the password in its properties to the new one.

Comment: This will change the password for <username> on the linux system, not the VPN.

Comment: @SetJmp who is controlling the server side of the VPN?

Comment: An administrator controls the server and I do not have login access.  I have just clarified the second part of the question to indicate I expect a client side solution.  On mac for example, when I attempt to login to the VPN with an expired password I am prompted to change the VPN password via a GUI.  The ideal Linux solution would work the same way instead of causing me to dig up the error message from a log file and then boot up a mac to change the password.

Comment: No. There is no common client side solution to change a password on a remote machine if it is already locked as far as I know. As for changing password _remotely_ for PPTP connection when it is already timed out I am also in doubt. However, the Mac's software is out of my scope so I guess it has the ability to know that the password will be expired soon so it warns you and offers to change it?